# How do I create TabControl and populate it by TabPages programmatically by loop in C#?

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I am new to C#, I want to create hierarchical TabControl by loop, where TabControl1 contains TabPages A1 & A2 and then in A1 create TabControl2, where TabControl2 contains B1 and B2, and where 1,2,3 indicate loop index. I would expect something like this picture below.

[sample picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDbrg.png)

[sample picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdLZe.png)

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int g = 0;
        int h = 4;

        while (g < h) 
        {
            g++;
            var parentTabControl = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            parentTabControl.TabPages.Add("A" + g.ToString());
            var page = parentTabControl.TabPages[0]; 
            var childTabControl = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            childTabControl.TabPages.Add("B" + g.ToString());
            page.Controls.Add(childTabControl);
            this.Controls.Add(parentTabControl);
        }

    }
```

but I got

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08Zgs.png)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: That sounds straightforward.  What problem are you having with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a minute to read the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) FAQ. Most importantly, please show us what you've tried so far, code-wise.

Comment: Thank you @BACON, any ideas?

Comment: Hi @vzwick, I edited my post..

Comment: @RojoL3L3 What exactly is your issue with the code? What does it (not) do? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @vzwick, I expect 3 TabControl by setting h to 4, obviously I am doing something wrong here. Because the output that I get with the code above is only "A1" tabpage and "B1" tabpage.

Comment: Where can we see your output?

Comment: @vzwick, I edited my post to include the output that I get.

Comment: Perfect. Now let me get this right: If `h == 4` you would expect to see 3 `TabControl`s (`A1, A2, A3`), each containing one child `TabControl` (`B1`, `B2`, `B3`). Correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thank you @vzwick

Comment: Set a breakpoint somewhere inside your `while` loop and see how often it gets hit, you're in for a surprise ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here your function

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int g = 0;
        int h = 3;
        var parentTabControl = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
        while (g < h) 
        {
            g++;
            parentTabControl.TabPages.Add("A" + g.ToString());
            var page = parentTabControl.TabPages[g-1]; 
            var childTabControl = new TabControl { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
            childTabControl.TabPages.Add("B" + g.ToString());
            page.Controls.Add(childTabControl);
        }
        this.Controls.Add(parentTabControl);
    }
```

you needed to take out from the loop the parent.
you created 4 parents that was cover one on the other.
and also if you want 3 you need to change h to 3.
maybe it is even better to change this loop to for loop.